# Python comparing results after predictions

Tags: python, dataframe, prediction

I have this dataframe

```
test_y
Out[55]: 
           Results
    47302     0
    65704     0
    63472     1
    47247     1
    5674      0
    5405      1
    65501     0
    14418     1
    18521     1
    7631      1
    1221      0
    23915     1
    10548     0
    18698     1
    46644     0
    56585     1
    50018     0
    54615     1
    22613     1
```

when I run the prediction I get an array which I can not compare to the dataframe

```
test_y_predictions = model.predict(test_X)

test_y_predictions
Out[57]: 
array([[0.49395287],
       [0.26348412],
       [0.6578461 ],
       ...,
       [0.74228203],
       [0.4677609 ],
       [0.6267687 ]], dtype=float32)
```

I want to find how many correct results I got

I tried this but got an error

```
test_y_predictions = round(test_y_predictions)
```

> TypeError: type numpy.ndarray doesn't define **round** method

How can I compare what I got from prediction and what I have?

Comment: To clarify, you are trying to round the values to the nearest integer in order to get 0/1 labels, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need this one.

```py
test_y_predictions.round()
```

```py
>>> a=np.array([[0.49395287],
       [0.26348412],
       [0.6578461 ],       
       [0.74228203],
       [0.4677609 ],
       [0.6267687 ]])
>>> a.round()
array([[0.],
       [0.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [0.],
       [1.]])
```

When you want to compare the prediction result with the labels, you can try `classification_report`

```py
metrics.classification_report(test_y, test_y_predictions)
```

Comment: @asmgx, check with `model.classification_report()`